# Unable to set "SetClickable" tag

Tags: set, qml, clickable

How can I disable Mouse Clicks in certain MouseAreas?

I am using the some code inside `MouseArea{ .... }` and want them to be disabled till the time a flag for them doesn't turn `TRUE`!

```
onClicked: {
                focus: true
                onClicked: pageLoader.source = "PAGE3.qml";
           }
```

There are multiple mouseAreas in the program. What is needed is to disable all other MouseAreas when one MouseArea has already been clicked and the page corresponding to that mouseArea is loaded using **loader** .
These mouseAreas are loaded as a matrix using the  `Grid` function of QML.

How can I do that?

Comment: According to docs http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-mousearea.html MouseArea doesn't have this property. Where did you get this name `setClickable`? Have you invented it yourself?

Comment: Sorry, My mistake. It was in `QHeaderView Class Reference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer! You need to add
`enable: false`

Example:
`Grid {

enable: true }`

This will enable the Grid and;

`Grid {

enable: false }`
This will disable the Grid!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    property bool clickable
    MouseArea {
            anchors.fill:parent
            onClicked: {
                    if (clickable)
                            console.log("clicked");
                    else 
                            console.log("unclickable");

            }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: clickable = true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't disable the MouseArea, it just prints values. Let me re-edit the question.

Comment: I was thinking that you load multiple mouse areas into grid and you want to disable some of them inside the grid. Not grid at whole. ANyway, I'm glad that you have gotten expected result.